# How we can add AsDoc comments to a component?

Tags: apache-flex, asdoc

I have a canvas based component, so when I check the asdoc comments, they have inherited comments of Canvas. can we remove that inherited comments, and add our own AsDoc comments..

Answer (score 0):

If you add your own ASDoc comments to your class, it should override the function it's replacing when extending it.

Comment: in case you extended class it works. but in case of MXML component.. it doesn't work.

Comment: The ability to add ASDoc comments to MXML components was added in Flex 4.  Assuming you are using Flex 4 the comment syntax in MXML for ASDOC is <!--- My ASDoc comment -->, for more check [the docs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WSd0ded3821e0d52fe1e63e3d11c2f44bc36-7ff2.html)